# Save sensors data on PC

Tags: esp8266, esp32

I am working between an esp8266 and esp32 (I still have some doubt on what to use), and I would like to save sensors data permanently somewhere on my PC. I don't have a SD shield and I am new on this kind of things. There's some simple and easy way to do that? Arduino IOT Cloud actually collect one data per second and seems to be the best solution, but it does not support esp32 Heltec v3. Thingspeak collect data every 15 seconds and I need to collect 4 samples per second.
Is there any alternative to simple send the data to a txt file on my computer?

Edit: I actually found out that the best and Easy way to save data on computer, not considering WiFi, Is the Data Streamer Add-ons of excel, which allows to print data on and excel sheet like It was a serial monitor. It's possibile to plot real time values and save It until million of rows every 100 milliseconds minimum.

Comment: How is your ESP connected to your PC? If there is a USB link, something like `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw -echo && cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > sensor-data.txt` should do it (the details are OS-dependent). If using WiFi, I would try [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat).